# Cognos: create date item as percentage of total

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am quite newbie in cognos. I wonder how I can create a variable as percentage from the total.
I have the following table containing a variable named compliant which can either be Y or No.

| Y | N | Total | percentage_Y_of_total% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 25% |

I created the Y and N variable with
`case when Complaint_VAR ('Y') then 'Compliant' else 'Non-Compliant' end`

**My question: How do I create percentage_Y_of_total variable? How do I create a data item as percentage of the total split by case when clause?**

Comment: Y / ( Y+ N) or Y/ total but that's too easy so I don't know if I'm missing some other aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to query explorer.  Tool box.  Drag data item to the details to create custom expressions

- Use function total and define the scope, let's call the data item **Y_Total**.  For example the expression would look like:

  Total(Y for company, year, month)
- Create another data item **Overal_Total** that gets the total rows of data
- Create a calculation data item called **percentage_Y_of_total%** that takes Y_Total divided by Overal_Total